# Is the empty line necessary for a http request without body

Tags: http, protocols

I know that in a http request, an empty line is used to seperate the header and the body. But what if there isn't any request body (For example for the GET or HEAD method request)? In this case, is an empty line after the header still necessary?

I've read the RFC doc of HTTP, but I didn't get any comment on this issue. Maybe I misunderstood or missed something?